# Number of primes of the form $2\cdot 3 \cdots 61+n$, $2 \le n \le 59$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

You  are  given  a  sequence  of  58  terms;  each  term  has  the  form  P+n  where  $P$  stands  for  the  product  $2\cdot3\cdot5\cdots61$ of  all  prime  numbers  less  then  or  equal  to  $61$,  and  $n$  takes,  successively,  the  values  $2,  3,  4,...59$.  Let  $N$  be  the number  of  primes  appearing  in  this  sequence.  Then  $N$  is.....

What i have understood that each term is composite.Then what to do...

Comment: If a number is composite, is it prime?

Comment: Can you explicitly prove that each number is composite?

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, if $n$ is equal to any one of the primes $p \leq 61$, the number is composite since we can factor out that particular prime. Then for each remaining value of $n$, consider those that are multiples of $2, 3, 5,...$ and in each of those cases, you too can factor out a common prime in the factorization of $P$ and $n$ individually. Observe that we do not even need to first consider $n$ as primes, as going through the multiples of each prime automatically takes care of that.

The [Sieve of Erastosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a good visual description of the process described above.

Answer (score 0):

Since $61!$ divided by all natural number from $[2,59]$,

we get that all of them is a composite number.

Id est, the answer is: $0$.